# What was Plan A for the Luchos?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, aseres-hadibros, deuteronomy, har-sinai, chumash

In Devarim we see that the Aron was made for the purpose of storing the Luchos, but those were for the 2nd Luchos (after Moshe broke the first ones). My question is what was Plan A? Meaning when Moshe went down the first time from Har Sinai with the Luchos, where was he going to put them? There was no Mishkan yet.

Comment: There was no mishkan the second time either.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sforno_on_Genesis,_Introduction.8

Comment: @shmosel There wasn't a mishkan but there was an aron https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.10.1.1?lang=bi